# Execute jQuery function each time JS function is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image "uploader" that converts images into base64 and displays as thumbnails inside the uploader. I have it set up so that you can add to it by dragging more images in after you have done 1 batch, and it will just add to the array and display more images with the ones you've already added.

I have a jQuery function to limit the characters on file name displayed under the image under the images, and a "show more" button will display the hidden text. I'm trying to fire this function each time a new batch of images is added, but I am struggling to figure out how to do this.

Below is my jQuery function as well as the  relevant bit of the js function that I need to modify to trigger this jQuery (I'm still learning the etiquette here...not sure if it's okay to only post the relevant bit so that I don't create a huge wall of text unnecessarily).

Also [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bn5fm76o/) (I've currently put this jQuery function on a 5 second timer so I can quickly drop in an image before it fires just to make sure it is working, as well as some text at the top  for the same purpose.) But I am just struggling with the syntax to fire this with each image added to the array.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Edit: for clarification, as of right now once the jquery function fires once, it will only truncate the text under the existing images, and any added after this are unaffected, and their captions show the full string of text. I am trying to limit the text and add a "read more" button for all images added. So I was under the impression I needed to trigger this function each time a new block of images is added. Apologies if this is not the best way to do this or I did a poor job of explaining.

JQ

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxLength = 5;
$(".show-read-more").each(function(){
    var myStr = $(this).text();
    if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
        var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
        var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
        $(this).empty().html(newStr);
        $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
        $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
    }
});
$(".read-more").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
    $(this).remove();
});
});
```

JS

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onloadend = () => {
//image and file name
let imageContainer = document.createElement("figure");
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = reader.result;
imageContainer.appendChild(img);
imageContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="caption"><p class="show-read-more"  id="caption">${name}</p></div>`;
imageDisplay.appendChild(imageContainer);
```

Comment: jQuery **is JavaScript**.  We're talking about one programming language here.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. Your code seems to work, you can drag image into the box and it shows the thumbnail. You can also drag more images into the box and it works as well.

Comment: What specific operation are you looking to invoke?  The call to `$(".show-read-more").each(function(){`?  You could put that in a function and call that function whenever you like...

Comment: @Swiffy sorry  I was not clear. I need the caption under the images to automatically hide excess text with a "read more" button to see the rest, and as of now any image that is added after the initial execution of the jquery function does not have it's caption truncated, it just shows the full text. So I was under the impression that I needed to fire this function each time new images are added, or do some kind of listen event. Apologies.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, I am still learning a lot as you can tell

Comment: you are just doing a foreach function in jquery, you are not triggering that piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a fork of your code where I think the problem is solved: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/v1nyLzbs/13/

I removed some things from the bottom of the code and now it's just this:

```
$(document).click('.read-more',function(e){
    const target = $(e.originalEvent.target);
    target.next('span.more-text').removeClass('hidden')
  target.remove();
});
```

Since those `.read-more` elements are not there when the document loads, we can't bind the click event handler directly to them. Instead, we bind the click event handler to the document and provide the `.read-more` selector as shown.

It's better to use `$(e.originalEvent.target)` instead of `$(this)` here for reasons I can't remember at this time, because I haven't used jQuery for a long while now, but I do remember that it's just how it's done.

I've added a simple `hidden` class to the bottom of your CSS code:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Because I changed your `fileHandler` function to work like this:

```
const fileHandler2 = (file, name, type) => {
  if (type.split("/")[1] !== "jpeg") {
    //File Type Error
    container.classList.remove("dropped");
    submit.classList.remove("hideit");
    error.innerHTML = "<span class=\"error-m\">One or more of the selected files are invalid. Files must be .jpg/.jpeg</span>";
    error.classList.remove("hideit");
    setTimeout(function(){
         error.innerHTML="";
        error.classList.add("hideit");


       },90000);
    return false;
  }
  error.innerText = "";
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    //image and file name
    let imageContainer = document.createElement("figure");
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = reader.result;
    imageContainer.appendChild(img);
    
    var maxLength = 5;
    
    if($.trim(name).length > maxLength){
      var newStr = name.substring(0, maxLength);
      var removedStr = name.substring(maxLength, $.trim(name).length);
      imageContainer.innerHTML += `<a class="read-more">read more...</a><span class="more-text hidden">${removedStr}</span>`;
    } else {
        imageContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="caption"><p class="show-read-more" id="caption">${name}</p></div>`;
    }
    
    imageDisplay.appendChild(imageContainer);
    
  };
};
```

It now checks the length of the file name and either outputs HTML for the read more button and the element which will be shown when the button is clicked. The element which will be shown when the button is clicked is initially hidden with the element having the `hidden` class. When the read more button is clicked, we remove the hidden class and also remove the read more button alltogether.

If the file name is not too long, the file name will be shown normally under the image.`

One thing I always want to say to new jQuery developers is to not get confused with the `$()` thing. There is nothing special about it and using it won't take you to some "jQuery world" separate from JavaScript.

The `$()` thing is a normal JavaScript function, but the function name is just `$`. You can pretty much make your "own jQuery" with:

```
const $ = function(selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Obviously that is a very simplified example, but the point is to show the unspecial nature of `$()`. The confusion comes from jQuery wrapping the result of the `$` function with all kinds of stuff of its own, so it's more like:

```
const $ = function(selector) {
    const jQueryObject = {
        element: document.querySelectorAll(selector),
        next: function() {},
        html: function() {},
        text: function() {},
        ...
    }

    return jQueryObject;
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Holy cow, thank you for taking the time to do that. There are a couple of minor tweaks I'll have to make because it's still a little buggy but that will be a good learning experience. I'm sure these are easy fixes but just typing it out in case anyone else sees this.

The caption automatically hides 100% of the text no matter what, and the "read more" button will display the text minus the first n characters (n = var maxLength). Also if you repeatedly click the dropzone it removes each element 1 by 1 just going up to the next parent element lmao.  I'll fix :). 

Thank you again so much.

Comment: I assume this is the proper fix, as it seems to be what your intention was. 

I just had to add  ${newStr} to the orginal span so it showed the truncated text and not just "read more" with nothing else, and then again add  ${newStr} right before the removed string, so when it unhides that hidden span, the original text is also there so it's not starting in the middle of the caption.

I really appreciate you doing all of that.

Comment: @neonfontana Yeah I think the main point here was to get the truncation and the button event to work. If you have major further problems, you'd have to post them as a new question. As for bugs, good idea to try to fix them as an excercise!